# novel frustration

Tags: structure, book

I need help. I have written 4 novels, 3 in kit form.I will try to be brief, but this is complicated. The stories are brilliant....and in current form unreadable.I am a conflicted writer hampered by the fact that I cannot type.I am both a manic writer,and also lazy.Once I get a thought,the whole novel pops into my head from beginning to end.At times I have written 16 pages or more at a sitting,not being disturbed in the least by screaming grandchildren,or blaring T V sets,then gone months without writing a thing.I NEVER get writers block,my problem is quite the opposite.When the creative juices are flowing I don t stop to correct the obvious spelling mistakes or malaprop (everything is handwritten)the upshot is that I write partial chapters,then jump to others and return later The results can be chaotic.Though I have improved considerably in my early

Comment: Is there a question in there?

Comment: What's "kit form"?

Comment: sorry, have trouble  navigating sites, half my question was missing, didn t know there was a space limit. Kit is where all the information is there in chapter form, but needs to be assembled

Comment: Welcome to Writers. While I sympathize with your issue, you might be better off asking this on a discussion forum, where people can talk about an issue and try to help. This is a Q&A site, where questions need to be answerable, meaning there can be a single answer. We've also decided as a community that questions asking what to write are off-topic. Have closed this for now, but if you have any clear, specific questions about writing, please feel free to ask them. You can also have a look at our site tour to get a feel for how this all works.

Comment: couched in gentle kindness,you fool no one,you are a snob of the worst kind.I would have had more respect for you had you said .....Please leave ,this is an exclusive club and your ilk are unwelcome. Very well ,I will go .If you are the type that has to get the last word in,I won t be here to see it,but if it will make you feel better,you can further excoriate me by leaving as nasty a message as you would like at Kenandrelczyk@yahoo.com

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

You have to fight your laziness, to stop procrastinating, because all the creativ part of this work (the inspiration, the story "popping out", the ideas, the plan, some brilliant dialog fragments) is the good part, the exciting part.

But then, if you want to make it real, there's not secret to it : you have to **work hard** (correcting, proofreading, (re)writing the less engaging parts of a chapter) and yes most of time you ideas seems less brilliant when you put them on paper, and yes it's frustrating and unpleasent, but then again, is the only path !

Switching from a novel to another novel is just a disguised way for escaping these inconviniences ! I was doing the same.

Comment: new to this half my question never made it. I am well aware of my shortcomings, rereading and the terror of inadequacy that comes along with it chief among them ( although when forced too I am always pleasantly surprised)Main problem is after I am finished a novel I don t want to see it again.My eventual question was How do I go about finding a co writer,preferably female aged 30 to 50(as a male I can only guess as to a females point of view )?

Answer (score 0):

I am not this type of a writer but in this case what I can suggest is when you have the jouces - just sit and write down what you think or even record it. Try to make it as a whole story as much as you can. Then when you have it somewhat structured go and talk to an editor and together consult how to write your story planning and putting deadlines.
What else I can suggest is collecting all your ideas, laying them down and then talking with a ghost writer who can finish your novel. I wouldn't do the seccond think though but it might work for you.